# Superscript and subscript, to immediate right of symbol without distortion

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I want to have an output like this

[image]

The closest I have come is with code `${A^{\leftarrow}}_(x, y, z + n)$` that gives me something like

[image]

where the subscript is way of the mark. Trying something like this `$A^{\leftarrow}_(x, y, z + n)$` gives even a greater distortion like this

[image].

I have tried using `\displaystyle` but not sure how to get the syntax correctly, to make it happen. Display style seems to work with things like limits or sums, and I am not sure how I could bend them to my needs. Any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the super/subscript in braces:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
A^{\leftarrow}_{(x, y, z + n)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I got the error. In trying to get it right amongst my many attempts I left out the {} out of the second (x, y, z + n) parameter, and just overlooked it. Should have done a better job, of catching my typo.